# Migrating .net core 2.2 to 3.1: error when running Program.cs Host.Run

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, migration

I have an error. In my Startup I used all these:

```
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddResponseCompression(); 
services.AddOptions();
services.AddCors();
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

**Program.cs:**

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .ConfigureWebHost(webBuilder => {
        webBuilder.UseKestrel(serverOptions => {
            // Set properties and call methods on options
        })
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
    })
   .Build();

host.Run();
```

> Unable to resolve service for type Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[App.Helpers.AppSettings]' while attempting to activate 'App.Startup'.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Kestrel?  Newer server are using HTTPS instead of HTTP so older versions of Kestrel may not work.

Comment: From 3.0+, the `Startup` constructor may only resolve `IConfiguration`, `IHostEnvironment`, and `IWebHostEnvironment` from DI: You can no longer inject `IOptions<AppSettings>`. If you still think you need to do this, include the code that uses `IOptions<AppSettings>` from your app so we can suggest an alternative approach. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#hostbuilder-replaces-webhostbuilder) in the docs.

Comment: @KirkLarkin , here u go now error is Startup Limit has reached. (AHCM 500.37).
Code:
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel(o => { o.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); })
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                  .Build();
                log.Info("host created");
                host.Run();

Comment: That's an entirely different issue, that you've already asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68004329/migrating-net-core-2-2-to-net-core-3-1-error-500-37-startup-time-limit).